# Ensure complete disjoint specialization MySQL/JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, specialization

I need to make sure that one entity specializes to exactly one entity.

For example, I have a Person that can be either a Student or a Teacher. Has to be one of them, can't be both. I want the Person associated with exactly one Student or Teacher.

I'm using MySQL and JPA.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is either a Student or a Teacher, can't be both, and can't become Teacher from Student and vice-versa, you can use inheritance:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Person {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Student extends Person {
}

@Entity
public class Teacher extends Person {
}
```

If Student and Teacher ar rather roles that a person can haven and a person can only have one role at a time (but can change role), use an attribute. For example:

```
public enum Role {
    TEACHER,
    STUDENT
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    private Role role;
    ...
}
```